# Undefined Lots of Variables

Tags: php, sql

```
<?php
  require("../config/config.php");
  require("../lib/db.php");
  $_POST['id'] = $uid;
  $_POST['pw'] = $upwunenc;
  $conn = db_init($config["host"],$config["duser"],$config["dpw"],$config["dname"]);
  $result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM userdata");
  $sql = "SELECT id,pw,nickname,pid FROM userdata WHERE id LIKE '$uid'";
  $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
  $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
  $row['id'] = $sqlid;
  $row['pw'] = $sqlpw;
  $row['nickname'] = $sqlni;
  $row['pid'] = $sqlpid;
  $upw = password_hash($upwunenc, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
  if ($uid === $sqlid) {
    if ($upw === $sqlpw) {
      $resulti = mysqli_query($conn, 'SELECT * FROM sitestatements');
      $sqli = 'SELECT link,pid FROM sitestatements WHERE upid = '.$_GET['pid'];
      $resulti = mysqli_query($conn, $sqli);
      $rowi = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resulti);
      $rowi['link'] = $link;
      session_start();
      $_SESSION['pid'] = $sqlpid;
      $_SESSION['nickname'] = $sqlni;
      header('Location: ./index.php');
    } else {
      echo "<script>window.alert('아이디나 비밀번호가 틀렸습니다. 회원가입하거나 다시 로그인해주세요.');</script>";
      echo "<script>window.location=('../login/login.php');</script>";
    }
  } else {
    echo "<script>window.alert('아이디나 비밀번호가 틀렸습니다. 회원가입하거나 다시 로그인해주세요.');</script>";
    echo "<script>window.location=('../login/login.php');</script>";
  }
?>
```

Notice: Undefined Variable: uid upwunenc uid sqlid sqlpw sqlpid upwunenc splid uid sqlpw

I Can't Find the Reason Why It's Happening. How Can I Fix It?

Comment: where do you think `$uid`,`$upwunenc` etc are defined?

Comment: line 4, 5, 11, 12, 13, 14,15, 16, 17.

Comment: line 4 looks for, but does not define `$uid`. so somewhere before line 4 should be `$uid = ????`

Comment: $uid = $_POST['id'];

Comment: Like this one??

Comment: thank you for your comment. it fixed.